# Get data from another table by just comparing the id using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from another table by just calling if the ID and data from another table is the same.

```
Table_1

Id  | name | lastname

1   | Fred | Moore
```

---

```
Table 2

Id  | table1_id 

1    |    1
```

I can already get and store the table 1 id to my table 2, but i want to echo the name and lastname from the table 1.

e.g. if table 2 table1_id is equal to Table_1 Id it will print the name and lastname .

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to do it, I already deleted my code cause it wont work

Comment: You should always show your attempt at coding it, even if it doesn't work. Who knows, maybe it only need a simple correction. But also, providing it here shows us there is good faith and that you're not just trying to scrounge free help without making any effort (which sadly happens here very frequently).

Comment: Anyway it sounds like what you mainly need to so is take a SQL course and learn about `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select table_1.name, table_1.lastname
from table_1
left join on table_2 on table_1.id = table_2.table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$a = "Table_1";
$b = "Table_2 ";

$allItem = $cxn->query("SELECT * 
FROM $a  
INNER JOIN $b
ON $a.id = $b.id
WHERE $a.id  = 1);

$allItem = $allItem->fetchAll();

$lastName = $allItem["lastname"];
$name = $allItem["name"];

?>
```

Maybe it could work!

Comment: $b = "Table 2"; will produce error when executing query

Comment: Thanks for the precision Subhashis Pandey i corrected in $b = "Table_2 ";

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
if(!$conn){
echo "Database Connection Failed!";
}

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT table1_id,first_name,last_name FROM table_1")or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query1)){
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $table1_id = $row1['table1_id'];
    $table1_first_name = $row1['first_name'];
    $table1_last_name = $row1['last_name'];

    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT table2_id,table1_id,first_name,last_name FROM table_2 WHERE table1_id='$table1_id' ORDER BY first_name,last_name ASC")or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn)); //check table1_id from table2 AND table1_id from table1 if matched
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    $table2_first_name = $row2['first_name'];
    $table2_last_name = $row2['last_name'];

    echo "First Name: ".$table2_first_name."<br>"; //print first name
    echo "Last Name: ".$table2_last_name."<br>"; //print last name
  }
}
else{
echo "No Result Found.";
}
?>
```